# FTP Backup Files On The Fly

Tags: shell, ftp, backup

I need to create a backup of each `vhost` directory on my server (incl. database), and FTP them to a remote server on the fly. Right now, the `/tmp/` directory keeps filling up and the backup exits with an error.

I've got the first part working (creating the backup), but the transfer is going wrong somewhere. Here's my code:

```
tar -g $INCFILE -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
| 
split -d -b 100m
| 
lftp -u UNAME,PASSWORD 8.8.8.8 -e 
    "mkdir -p $FTPD/$NOW && 
     cd $FTPD/$NOW && 
     lcd $BACKUP && 
     put backup-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).gz && 
     quit"
```

Please note: **I've split the code for readability** - it's all on one line in the script.

The error I'm getting is:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
/usr/local/bin/ftpbackup.sh: line 71: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/local/bin/ftpbackup.sh: line 72: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/local/bin/ftpbackup.sh: line 73: echo: write error: No space left on device
Null message body; hope that's ok
temporary mail file: No space left on device
No space left on device
. . . message not sent.
```

At the moment, it seems I'm piping the result of the `tar` to the local server (`/tmp/`).

How can I get that working so that I'm piping the result of the `tar` directly to the remote server? Thanks.